# Is this code correct for checking for prime number in c using functions?

Tags: c

Is this code correct for checking prime number using functions. I am not getting any syntax errors but it is always showing prime regardless of what I enter.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int prime(int);

void main() {
    int n, count, a;

    printf("enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    prime(n);

    if (count == 2)
        printf("prime");
    else
        printf("not prime");
}

int prime(int n) {
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        return (count);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you looked at the result of `prime()`

Comment: Your output depends on the value of `count` which is uninitialised, so **Undefined Behaviour**. Tomorrow, *nothing* you enter will be prime. And if you don't mind me saying, your `prime` function is naive, since (for one thing) any divisor greater than the square root of `n` will have already been checked by way of its other divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function `prime` -

```
 int prime(int n) {
 int i, count = 0;
 for (i = 1; i <n; i++) {       // go till n (or better till sqrt of n)
     if (n % i == 0) {
         count++;
     }
     if(count==2){             // if count is 2 get out of loop
          break;
        }
   }
   return count;       // return out of loop
}
```

In you function `main`-

**1.** `void main` **->** `int main(void)`

**2.** write you `if else` satatements as follows -

```
if (count == 2)
    printf("not prime");
else
    printf("prime");
```

**3.** initialize `count` to `0` in `main`.
       call function as -

```
          count=prime(n);
```

Comment: @WeatherVane  Not a problem Sir !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your prime function doesn't work properly. In the first for loop you're doing `n & 1 == 0` which always is true, and in the last loop `n % n == 0` also is always true

```
int prime(int n){
  int i;
  int isPrime = 1;
  for(i=2;i<sqrt(n) && isPrime;i++){ // do the loop while 2<i<sqrt(n) and n isPrime, once you know it's not prime don't loop anymore
      isPrime = n%i; // If it's 0 then it's not prime (isPrime = 0) else it's true         
  }
  return isPrime;
}
```

Edit: Optimized the for loop until i=sqrt(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* i just needed to take input of value count and store it in a variable*/
#include<stdio.h>
int prime(int);
int main(void)
{
    int n,count,a,m;

    printf("enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    m=prime(n);

    if(m>2)
        printf("not prime");
    else
        printf("prime");
}
int prime(int n)
    {
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return(count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function return `true` if the number is prime and `false` if not.

```
int prime(int n){
  int i; 
  for(i= 2; i < n; i++){
    if(n % i ==0 && i != n)
      return true;  
  }
  return false;
}
```